# How to correctly quote JSON (with variable) in YAML

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run a command from gitlab CI / CD pipeline. The command itself takes json as one of the argument. The json is construction using custom CI variable. It works with hard coded version as following.

```
my_command --args '{ "version": "v.0.0.2"}'
```

But when
VAR="v.0.0.2"

None of the following seems to work

```
my_command --args '{ "version": $VAR}'
my_command --args '{ "version": \"$VAR\"}'
my_command --args '{ "version": \"{$VAR}\"}'
my_command --args '{ "version": "${VAR}"}'
my_command --args '{ "version": \" ${VAR} \" }'
my_command --args '{ "version": \" "${VAR}" \" }'
```

For context, this is a small CI pipeline where it's used. VAR is CI custom variable.
stages:
- test

```
run_test:
    image: custom_image
    stage: test
    script:
    - | 
      my_command --args '{ "version": "v.0.0.2"}'
```

Can you please help how to quote it correctly? There are JSON in YAML examples online but none involves using variables.

Comment: Could you please provide some more context on how your gitlab ci config looks like and where this snippet is placed? I assume the issue comes from the single quotes you used around the json. Those won’t work locally either if you export VAR and then use one of the commands...

Comment: That is spot on, ended up replacing it with double quotes and worked. I thought single and double quotes were mostly interchangeable in this context (provided we escape correctly). But apparently they are not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, although by trial and error instead some document I can refer to. Following escape works.

```
my_command --args "{\"version\": \"${VAR}\"}"
```